# Git remove feature but retain for other branch

Tags: git

I have a bunch of commits in a linear commit history. At some point I added a feature that was useful for testing but should not be in production. I would now like to split out a `testing` branch with that feature but would like to be able to rebase `testing` onto `master` in the future to keep it up to date. So my current commits look like:

```
A-B-C-D-E
```

My solution was to add another commit `F` to `master` that removes the feature. Then create a branch `testing` and revert commit `F`:

```
# Do work to remove feature
git commit -a -m "F"

git checkout -b testing
git revert master
```

So now my commit history looks like:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F (master)
           \
            F' (testing)
```

Where `F'` is the reversion of `F`.

Is this the best way to do it? Is there something easier that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure my way of doing this is any easier, but I prefer the way it leaves my history.

You can perform an interactive rebase to [reorder the commits](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/20/reorder-commits-with-rebase.html), putting your testing commit on top.

You can then make a new testing branch from your master, which now has that commit on top.

Then you can rebase your master or just reset the pointer, to drop that top commit off the master branch.

Comment: Would OP still be able to rebase `testing` onto `master` with this technique?

Comment: Yes, because at the end of this all `testing` is is `master` plus one commit on the top of the stack.

Comment: Unfortunately the feature in question is the product of multiple commits that are not next to each other in the history. This solution also messes with anyone else who has the code checked out and wants to merge back in. Good alternative though if you don't care about either of those things - upvoted.

Comment: In that case do you really want to remove this code at all? Could you not hide it behind a feature switch or something? Otherwise, yea I think a revert chain like you are suggesting is best bet.